# Looping through an array in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In Sheet1, cell A1 I have the following text: A-B-C-D-E-F

I need to loop through this text and I have written the following code that works fine:

```
dim w as worksheet
dim s as variant
dim p as integer

set w = Worksheets(1)

p = 0
For Each s In Split(w.Range("A1").Value, "-")
    p = p + 1
    MsgBox Split(w.Range("A1").Value, "-")(p - 1)
Next s
```

The above code pops up the Message box showing each of the letters one after the other, as expected.

BUT I am not happy with the repeating of Split(w.Range("A1").Value, "-"), declaring the array for the loop and once again for every occurrence within the loop.

So I have tried with:

```
MsgBox s.Value
```

but it throws an error about an object being requested.

Why can I not use the Value property given that "s" is a variant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like this

```
dim w as worksheet
dim s as string

set w = Worksheets(1)

For Each s In Split(w.Range("A1").Value, "-")
    MsgBox s
Next
```

When you assign any object to a variant then it behaves like the object assigned to it and has only those properties which are present in object. In your For Each split you assigned string to s and string variables return their value directly and not by objString.Value.

Comment: Sure, but why not s.Value?

Comment: Updated the answer please check.

Comment: Spot on answer that confirms the interrogations I had. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`Split` returns a string array which is separated into *individual* strings by the `For Each`, so you can just pass those to `MsgBox` as is.

So, rather than using `s.Value`, just use `s` on its own.

In other words:

```
dim w as Worksheet
dim s as Variant

set w = Worksheets(1)

For Each s In Split(w.Range("A1").Value, "-")
    MsgBox s
Next
```

Comment: I did this one minute after I asked the question ;-). But my question remains, does "s" inherits the property of the array, meaning it can be treated as a text variable?

Comment: @CloseISQ, that's moot since I've specifically declared `s` as a `string` so it will only "inherit" the value of the string from `for each`. If you specifically declare it as variant, possibly it would be the same as if you assigned a string to it (since the `foreach/split` combo gives a string) but that's not something I would suggest. Variants are fine if you want to be able to hold many different types in it but here you have a clear case that _everything_ you're mucking about with is a string.

Comment: I have tried this. VBA doesn't let me pass the result of the split function to the string variable "s". It complains about a missing requested object.

Comment: @CloseISQ, actually you're right, it does require a variant (otherwise you get a for each control variable must be a variant or object). However, the variant is still treated as a string in the context of the `for each` so you still use `s` rather than `s.Value`. Have changed code to the correct version, tested in Excel itself.